# Network Issues - How to distinguish problems with ISP and wifi backhaul - how to do a packet loss test

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, isp

I currently live in the basement and Ethernet hasn't been drawn down here, hence I purchased Netgear Orbi rbr750 to hopefully get some decent performance. Now I have the router upstairs and my computer connected with a cable from one of the satellites.

Internet speeds have been flawless with no loss over the distance, but sometimes I lose connection whilst gaming. I have realized that my ISP is at fault for most of the disconnections, since it shows me in the app that the router itself is getting no signal from the ISP. However I'm not sure if the ISP is always at fault.

Hence I'm wondering if there is an easy way of doing a "packet loss" test over a long duration of time that is not affected by the ISP working or not, or if there is some software that does this for me.

Comment: Are you able to connect a computer by Ethernet to the ISP Modem. This way you can check the ISP performance. Very hard to work out the issue with the current setup.

Comment: Hmm, not really. I dont have a laptop, but in reality I just want to test my wifi backhaul whilst I'm trying to have them change ISP for me

Comment: Is there a way to temporarily install Ethernet (neatly downstairs) to the computer?

Comment: Welcome to SU. The only packet loss test you can do without the ISP affecting is traffic between your system and the router. The tool is `ping`. Command to run continuous ping on *NIX (incl. MacOS) is `ping <router IP>`, on Windows `ping -c <router IP>`. To have steady Wi-Fi connectivity ensure that the router or the satellite aren't located behind a TV, next to a microwave etc...

Comment: ISP modems often have logging in the admin functions.  I've used it to troubleshoot 2G WIFI channel hopping etc.  Once you have a time frame with a blip, check the modem logs to see if anything was going on. Example ISP reconnection, WIFI channel hopping etc.    Once you know what is going on you will know how to address it.